# Angular templates in vendor->javascript->templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to setup an angular rails app.
Here is what I have upto now https://github.com/RohitRox/ngrails

My setup looks something like this:

```
|- app
|- config
|- more rails folders
.
.
|- vendors
  |- assets
    |- stylesheets
    |- javascripts
      |- app.js
      |- templates
        |- home.html
```

I have gem 'angular-rails-templates'
and my app.coffee

```
@app = angular.module('ngRails', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.router',
  'templates'
])
.config([ '$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) ->

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'assets/templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')

])

@app.run(->
  console.log 'angular app running'
)
```

I never got it to work, it only shows blank screen. I search and tried a lot but could not got it working.

Comment: look in console and network tabs of dev tools for clues

Comment: There is no any error or network requests.

Comment: not even any template requests? Do you have `ng-app` in html ?

Comment: Yes I do. There is no any logs or anything  that's why I am not being able to find what's going on.

Comment: `otherwise` value should start with `/` ...what shows up in url?

Comment: Suddenly I found out:
http://localhost:3000/#/home   -> doesn't works
http://localhost:3000/#/  -> works

Comment: no url set for that in code shown ...state and url aren't same thing

Comment: that was the catch "state and url aren't same thing". Thnks.